# Using intensity transformation from a given graphic in a matrix

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, I have to transform the intensity of an image using this given graphic:

[image: graphic]

where s=T(r)

I absolutely have no idea about this transformation. It's for an homework, can someone help me at least to recognize the function?

Comment: Please can you be more specific about what you wanna achieve? I'm personally interested. What about the transformation?

Comment: the Graphic only represents a modification of intensity for an existing picture. Here, s= 2r - 20 on the interval of 10 20, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Can someone explain me why the negative rep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the equation of a line, y=ax+b...
in matlab notation:

```
 r=linspace(0,30,1000); %this can be whatever r units are... r=0:0.1:100 etc.
 T=2*(r-10).*(r>=10 & r<=20);
 plot(r,T)
```

will yield the plot you just draw...

Comment: my question was more about the recognition of this intensity transformation so that I will be able to transform a matrix..

Comment: So you're just looking for the name some people use for it? (like sawtooth transform or something?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was s = 2r - 20 on the interval of [10, 20] and 0 otherwise.

Then, using an existing image, it's possible to modify the intensity.